# Python numpy.where: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index; on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a list of dictionaries (this is an example of some data grabbed from the database).

And by using a numpy.where clause I'd like to put all items with a certain index into another list

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
import numpy
from operator import itemgetter
from decimal import *

lightcurve_data = {}
lightcurve_data['stars'] = [{u'delta_j2000': Decimal('66.113525'), u'calibrated_error': 0.0442272797226906, u'id': 35549943L, u'filter': u'V', u'date': 2458008.64520255, u'calibrated_magnitude': Decimal('12.5425'), u'alpha_j2000': Decimal('325.777614')}, {u'delta_j2000': Decimal('66.113535'), u'calibrated_error': 0.0246241167187691, u'id': 38672301L, u'filter': u'R', u'date': 2458038.52371412, u'calibrated_magnitude': Decimal('11.8814'), u'alpha_j2000': Decimal('325.777077')}]


stars_for_filter = sorted(lightcurve_data['stars'], key=itemgetter('calibrated_magnitude'), reverse=True)
coord_list = SkyCoord(map(itemgetter('alpha_j2000'), stars_for_filter), map(itemgetter('delta_j2000'), stars_for_filter), frame='fk5', unit=u.degree)


index_array = [1., 1.]

median_ra = numpy.zeros(int(numpy.max(index_array)), dtype=float)

lightcurve_data['seperated'] = {}

for i in range(0, len(median_ra)):
    check_in_index_array = numpy.where(index_array == i + 1)
    key = 'some unique key'
    # This bit works
    median_ra[i] = numpy.median(coord_list[check_in_index_array[0]].ra.degree)
    # The rest doesn't...
    lightcurve_data['seperated'][key] = []
    lightcurve_data['seperated'][key] = lightcurve_data['stars'][check_in_index_array[0]]
```

However, when running this code I get the following exception:
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`
Interestingly the same use of `check_in_index_array[0]` works on a list of AstroPy SkyCoord's.

The full traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "[redacted]/views.py", line 1192, in lightcurve
    lightcurve_data['seperated'][key] = lightcurve_data['stars'][check_in_index_array[0]]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Is there any way I can fix this exception? Or perhaps go about this in a different way?

Thanks,

Will.

Comment: Please submit an [mvce](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) -- what is `index_array`, what is `median_ra`, what is `lightcurve_data['seperated']`? How can you expect us to answer this question in its current form? Also, what is the **full** traceback of your error?

Comment: Updated to include a longer code fragment and traceback as per comment suggestion

Comment: @Will, I think the key word is **minimal**: [mcve]. The error is likely reproducible in 5lines of code.

Comment: I've removed a couple of lines of code - but any fewer and the index_array and median_ra won't be able to be built (asked for in a previous comment). Would you prefer these to be defined as constants instead and any dynamic generation of them removed?

Comment: Try testing your code in a fresh session to see whether we can run your code. What's `SkyCoord` ?

Comment: I've removed any dymamic generation of the index_array, the code did run with the same exception in a fresh session (as the mvce link notes) and I've added the required imports to the code fragment.

Comment: I've also added back in the SkyCoord example code.

Comment: What does `check_in_index_array[0]` produce?  It looks like `lightcurve_data['stars']` is a list with 2 elements (both dictionaries).  As such it can only be index with `0` or `1`, or a single element array with the same values.

Comment: In this particular example, it produces the empty list, `[]`

Comment: `coord_list` apparently is `ndarray` like in that it accepts lists and/or arrays as indices, including `np.array([])`.  But a `list` does not accept that kind of indexing.  The result of `where(...)[0]` does not work with a list, regardless of how many items it finds.   `alist[np.array(0)]` works, but `alist[np.array([0])]` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248527/python-numpy-where-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a?noredirect=1#comment89481722_51248527) I've been able to answer this question by converting `lightcurve_data['stars']` from a Python list to a NumPy array.

```
array_stars = numpy.asarray(lightcurve_data['stars'])
```

then

```
lightcurve_data['seperated'][key] = array_stars[check_in_index_array[0]]
```

The exception no-longer occours - all works well. Thank you!